# Como chamar uma modelo de página dentro de um shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Criei um short code em um plugin que me retorna do banco usuários cadastrados e agora quero que abra uma visualização de perfil quando clicar no nome de tal usuário, porem não sei como criar esse novo modelo de página que ira abrigar conteúdo X de tal usuário que será transportado pela URL. Tentei adicionar esse modelo dentro da pasta do plugin porem além de ficar algo como "`../wp-content/plugins/meu_plugin/meu_modelo_de_perfil.php`", ele sai fora do template do tema mesmo utilizando o `get_header(), get_sidebar(), get_footer()` diz que a função não foi definida, não acho que seja a forma certa ou completa de fazer tal coisa.

Comment: Cria um custom post type e faz um ACF atrelado a ele. Aí você não terá trabalho com nada.

Comment: Hmm... Não me parece certo criar um CPT pra utilizar apenas 1 pagina que ira servir como modelo, saca?! Resolveria, mas não é o ideal e é isso que procuro, algo mais direto e "certo". Fora que paginas do CPT podem ser apagadas pelo wp-admin.

Comment: Com includes eu consegui trazer a funcionalidade dessa página que criei, esta parecendo uma pagina normal criada pelo wp-admin que é exatamente o que eu quero porem ainda não consegui resolver o problema da url que está assim: `localhost/MEUSITE/wp-content/plugins/MEUPLUGIN/front/views`/PERFIL.php
Quero que essa url agora fique curta, sem as pastas, algo como: `localhost/MEUSITE/PERFIL`